# Dump & remove contents of a DLQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

I know that `activemq-admin` has an option to purge a queue, so I can easily purge a DLQ if I want to.  But what I would like to do is dump the contents of a DLQ to a file before purging it (or manually remove each item and write it to a log).  Is it possible to do this with `activemq-admin`, or is there another similar tool that's readily available?  I've done a bit of searching but haven't come across anything, so I figure I'd ask here before trying to implement it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the tool "[A](https://github.com/fmtn/a)" for that task. It can dump the content of a queue to one file per message.

Example usage to read a queue and dump it to one file per message (dump.txt, dump-1.txt, .. dump-n.txt).

`a -b tcp://example.org:61616 -g -c 1000 -o dump.txt ActiveMQ.DLQ`

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this tool

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I downloaded & built 'a' but when I run it no log file is created.  All I get is a message 'Operation completed in 11ms (excluding connect)'  and nothing more.  I'm sure I have the broker parameter set properly and the name of the DLQ as well. Is there any sort of debugging capability in 'a'?

Comment: try adding -w 2000 or similar. no debug though

Comment: Whoops, my bad.  I was specifying an empty DLQ.  I changed to use the right DLQ, and now if I specify '-c 100' I end up with 100 text files, but every one of them is 0 bytes in size.  If I don't specify a value for -c then I get as many empty text files as there are items in the DLQ. So it's doing something right, but still not providing me with the contents of the messages.